# Does the HTML5 worker threads feature expose the number of cores on a machine?

Tags: javascript, html, cpu, worker-thread

I'm playing with HTML5 [worker threads](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/workers/basics/) and I want to partition out some work according to available cores. Is there a way to get the number of cores on the machine from JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to estimate the number of cores with:
https://github.com/oftn/core-estimator

demo:
http://eligrey.com/blog/post/cpu-core-estimation-with-javascript